# Question is different with '“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument'

Tags: python, function, arguments

I am new to python. I run a code like this:

```
def funtest(L=[]):
    L.append(L)
    return L
print(funtest([2]))
print(funtest([3]))
print(funtest([4]))
```

real output is in below.

```
[2, [...]]
[3, [...]]
[4, [...]]
```

It is not a new problem about the Mutable Default Arguments. see before:
[Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

According to the Mutable Default Arguments rule, I thought the output should like this:

```
[2, [...]]
[2,3, [...]]
[2,3,4, [...]]
```

Does anyone have idea about that? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: because that question so I am asking this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

default arguments come in picture when you don't pass any arguments to the function,

here you are passing arguments to the function namely `[2]`, `[3]` and `[4]` and hence default value is not being used

in your question you mention that for first print output should be `[2, [...]]` if you are able to understand that , then next ones are exactly same as default argument never comes in the picture.. just focus on how `[2, [...]]` came

Comment: I cannot understand the meaning of default value is not being used. The document say "Python’s default arguments are evaluated once when the function is defined." so I got a infinite [...]. Then I made L=[2], so I got [2, [...]]. It is right according to the saying "if you use a mutable default argument and mutate it, you will and have mutated that object for all future calls to the function as well." so I make L=[3], it should be [2,3, [...]]. right?

Comment: @JiangLiang yes, you are creating a default argument when you define the function.  Then you never use it, because you always call the function with an explicit argument.